# How to access clicked polygon to change it's style in Google Maps Api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm using a code similar the one below to display buildings KML Layer. Click event works and i get name and HTML. What i need to do is, I want to change style of the clicked polygon/line. Let say I want to change border width. How can i do that?

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: {
            lat: 41.876,
            lng: -87.624
        }
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
        map: map
    });

    ctaLayer.addListener('click', function(kmlEvent) {
        //need to change style of the clicked element here.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the styling of a KmlLayer using the API.

Options:

1. use a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) (import your KML into a FusionTable, you can dynamically style polylines from a FusionTable).
2. use a 3rd-party KML parser, like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geoxml-v3/) to render the KML as native Google Maps JavaScript API v3 polylines, then modify those.  Note that the 3rd-party parsers are subject to the same domain security policy for the KML, so can only access KML from other domains through a proxy.

[example using geoxml3 (polylines change to yellow on mouseover)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linkto.html?filename=cta.xml)

Comment: geoxml3 is awesome! no reference so needs some code digging but still awesome.

Comment: Yeah, there used to be some documentation (not great, but at least something), but that went away when google code got shut down and the archive migrated to GitHub.  I have been meaning to reconstruct that.  It is available on [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20140710213603/http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/w/list)